# INImage from widgets intent collection is tinted with default blue color

Tags: ios, swift, widget, widgetkit

I'm building an app that contains iOS 14 widgets. User can change widget content by pressing on **Edit Widget**, and selecting it from provided intent collection. For  `INObjectCollection` I'm using an array of `INObject` and for each object I'm setting an image this way:

```
    let image = INImage(url: imageRemoteURL, width: 80, height: 80)
    let myObject = MyCustomObject(identifier: "an id", display: "some text", subtitle: nil, image: image)
    // MyCustomObject is a subclass of INObject
```

In the list images are displayed properly, but after selecting an item and opening again the view by pressing on **Edit Widget** - image is shown all system blue, also big sized. See attached screenshot:

[image]

I could find only [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/660141?answerId=641930022#641930022) topic on the issue but with no solution yet.

If I would use an image from app bundle, then a solution would be to set **Original** for **Render As**, but no idea how to fix this when using a remote image URL.
Another problem is image size, which is too large.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Edward's hints I managed to fix my issues this way:

```
func getIntentImage(imageLink: String) -> INImage?
{
    guard let url = URL(string: imageLink),
          let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url),   // may use image local caching
          var image = UIImage(data: imageData) else
    {
        return nil
    }
    let maxSize: CGFloat = 80
    let size = CGSize(width: maxSize, height: maxSize)
    if let resizedImage = image.resizeImage(targetSize: size)
    {
        image = resizedImage
    }
    return INImage(uiImage: image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal))
}

// Image resizer:
extension UIImage
{
    func resizeImage(targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage?
    {
        let size = self.size
        
        let widthRatio = targetSize.width / size.width
        let heightRatio = targetSize.height / size.height
        
        // Figure out what our orientation is, and use that to form the rectangle
        var newSize: CGSize
        if widthRatio > heightRatio
        {
            newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * heightRatio, height: size.height * heightRatio)
        }
        else
        {
            newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * widthRatio, height: size.height * widthRatio)
        }
        
        // This is the rect that we've calculated out and this is what is actually used below
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)
        
        // Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1)
        self.draw(in: rect)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        return newImage
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you managed to fix it! I tried to use it myself too, but get crash as `"+[INImage imageWithUIImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xXXXXX"` on `return INImage(uiImage: image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal))`.

Comment: @EdwardMordrake make sure you `import IntentsUI`

Comment: Looks like this only works on iOS 15. On iOS 14 `INImage` created from a `UIImage` just won't show up.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Image Size

I had the same issue with INImage's size in intent and found out this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/inimage/1648800-imagesize but couldn't find anything about how to use it properly so eventually decided on removing the intent image at all. Maybe it helps you!

### 2. Blue Tint

You can change the image's default rendering type in your asset catalog or programmatically, and this should remove tint color.

##### - Asset Catalog

Click on the image you want to change in your asset catalog, then go to the Attributes Inspector, and change the "Render As" attribute to "Original Image".

##### – Programmatically

INImage itself actually has a way to set rendering mode, but it is set as private and using this API could get your application rejected by Apple. So,  if you're planning to release it on App Store keep this in mind.

The "legal" solution is to use INImage(uiImage:) and set the rendering mode on the UIImage.

```
var renderedImage: UIImage? = UIImage(named:"myImage")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

let image = INImage(uiImage: renderedImage, width: 40, height: 40)
```